# Non project files in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, projects-and-solutions

On my project in PhpStorm usually the background for my project files is black.

I did a reverse in the git console to cancel some changes. From those changes the background color changed for yellow color. It appears it's for non project files.

Then I pulled the main branch and checked out on, but the color doesn't change... Even if I change for local or remote branch the problem persists.

Does anyone has an idea to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

I'm using PhpStorm 2023.2 version.

I changed the branches for local or remote.
I cloned the project but issue persists.

Comment: You might need to re-create the project .idea folder. To do that, move (do not delete) it somewhere (when a project is closed) and re-open the project.